# Rails link_to full url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm trying to get a link_to to generate the full url link of a survey in my sample survey app. The way I'm doing it is this in my mailer view:

```
<p>The survey is located <%= link_to("here", survey_url(@survey)) %>.</p>
```

The link that's generated is `http://localhost:3000/surveys/2`.

However, when the same code is run in production, the link that's generated is `http://example.herokuapp.com/surveys/2` when it should be `http://example.com/surveys/2`.

The config files:

development.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000'}
```

production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://example.com'}
```

Any idea why heroku is adding `.herokuapp` to the end of the host url/what I can do to generate the url as `http://example.com/surveys/2`?

Comment: any chance there's a another config line overriding it later?

Comment: Does the domain where your application is deployed contains herokuapp?

Comment: @DGM - I feel like such an idiot. It was being overridden...

Comment: Happens to me all the time, and I usually find it shortly after asking a question. :D

Comment: If you want to toss that as an answer I can accept it as well :)